# Android Media Image to Bitmap Conversion for Tensorflow Lite

Tags: java, android, image, tensorflow, bitmap

I am taking the camera input and processing it with **Tensorflow Lite** model to detect the image and gesture. Tensorflow lite model is **taking bitmap as an input**. I am taking the camera image which is in **android media image** format. Here my problem is I am trying to convert the media image to bitmap. I have found the following.

```
  val buffer: ByteBuffer = image!!.planes[0].buffer
        val bytes = ByteArray(buffer.capacity())
        buffer.get(bytes)
        val bmp:Bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.size, null)
```

But the converted bitmap is null always. Please guide me in the right way where I am going wrong.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The null return value suggests that the image data could not be decoded when you call `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray`. You may check your input contents first.

Here is a link to another similar question about how to convert android.media.image to Bitmap : [How to convert android.media.Image to bitmap object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41775968/how-to-convert-android-media-image-to-bitmap-object)

If it doesn't work, you may also try to check and handle Java error, where this question may be helpful [How do I keep track of Java Exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60022726/how-do-i-keep-track-of-java-exceptions)